# PHP exec can't access FFMPEG. while I can in command prompt

Tags: php, path, command-line-interface, exec, command-prompt

I installed FFMPEG on windows. I added it to my path variable. I can access ffmpeg in the command prompt regardless of which folder I am in (which tells me ffmpeg + the path variable is working like expected).

PHP

```
exec('ffmpeg -y -i C:/wamp64/test.mp4 -strict -2 -b:v 500k -vf scale=-2:123 C:/wamp64/test.mp4 2>&1', $output);
$output = implode(' -|- ', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Var_dump

```
'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, -|- operable program or batch file.
```

when I copy the exact same commando (`ffmpeg -y -i C:/wamp64/test.mp4 -strict -2 -b:v 500k -vf scale=-2:123 C:/wamp64/test.mp4 2>&1`) in my command prompt it works perfectly. Regardless of folder location.

**Do I need to take additional/different steps for PHP to be able to find `ffmpeg`?**

Comment: Looks like windows blocking another app to access terminal, have you tried to exec like this `C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe`?

Comment: @PutraPurba Yes this works, but I want to also use a library, which doesn't use full paths.

Comment: is C:\ffmpeg\bin already added to PATH var?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try use PHP defined constant

```
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
```

instead of / ?

Also, you have to use full path to your ffmpeg.exe program if it is not in your %PATH% e.g.:

```
'C:' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Program Files' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'ffmpeg' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bin'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'ffmpeg.exe'
```